# How to enable virtualization in Citrix VDI

Tags: android-emulator, virtualization, citrix, haxm

I want to install Intel HAXM (to make the android emulator faster) but the installer says that my computer "does not support Virtualization Technologies (VT-x)".

Is there a way that my admin can enable this for a VDI?

Answer (score 1):

enable VT-X from BIOS in your boot menu. Then visit the intel page for downloading the HAXM installer. use a search engine to find it...

Comment: I agree with this answer, just some added notes though - even if you get this far chances are you are going to have a problem with open gl (libOpenglRender.dll). You can attempt to un-check the option "Use Host GPU" by editing the target AVD and see what happens. This has worked for me in the past.